# Path Variable or Request parameter?

Tags: spring, rest, api, endpoint

When we design `Rest` apis, it is said that use `Path Variable` when you need to identify a resource and `Request Parameters` when you need to do operations like sorting, filtering, searching, pagination. Let us take a scenario of `Employee`:

Employee has three fields like `name`, `companyName`, `socialSecurityNo`.

Now i want an Employee with a `socialSecurityNo = ABC`.

It seems fine to have endpoint with path variable like `/employees/{socialSecurtityNo}`, since we are identifying a resource.

Also it seems intuitive that we are filtering on the basis of `socialSecurityNo` and have an endpoint like `/employees?socialSecurityNo=ABC`

What will be the right way as i am confused and think that both apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good question.

`/employees?socialSecurityNo=ABC`

is filtering all employees on `socialSecurityNo`. If `socialSecurityNo` is unique to an employee, there's no point in this endpoint existing and a client should use `/employees/{socialSecurtityNo}`.

There's nothing wrong with filtering on a unique field value (`socialSecurtityNo`) and if a client finds it easier to use this version (for whatever technical reason) then that's fine. There is no 'right' way. The ultimate reason APIs exist is to allow valuable work to be done by a client. Work with the client to allow that to happen but keep best practice in mind and know when the solution isn't the best but is the most practical in the situation.

I would expect to see:

```
/employees?surname=Smith
```

as this is filtering on a non unique field value and should return a collection of `Employee` objects.

The 'right' thing to do is keep the results consistent. If you have both ways of finding an employee, make sure the returned result is the same in each case.

Comment: I was assuming the `socialSecurityNo` to be unique so it makes sense to use path variable according to your answer.